# AWS SDK S3 Socket Closed exception

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My application uses close to 10 threads, each of which makes perhaps 7,000 Put Requests to S3 per minute.  (I'm running it on a powerful EC2 box which can handle the load quite well.)  It runs beautifully for close to an hour, but, after an hour, gets `Unable to execute HTTP request: Socket Closed` exceptions:

```
        http.AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Socket Closed
    java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.setOption(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1105)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setSoTimeout(SSLSocketImpl.java:2414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.isDataAvailable(SocketInputBuffer.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.isResponseAvailable(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:246)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.isResponseAvailable(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:47)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:713)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:518)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:446)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:256)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3641)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1438)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:128)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.upload(UploadMonitor.java:176)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:134)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

The Put Requests are done asynchronously, using the AWS SDK TransferManager.  I imagine that, in the time it takes for one put request to fully complete, about 10 have been made asynchronously.

Googling that exception, I found two possible causes:

1. The limit on MaxConnections.  I've raised it from the default 50 to 3000, to no avail.
2. Premature garbage collecting.  I've tried keeping a reference to the `Upload` objects returned by TransferManager (in an concurrent queue), and, again, no help.

How can I fix this? Again, the app runs well for close to an hour, but, consistently, hits this wall after about an hour.  (I'm running on Amazon AMI Linux on EC2.)

### Update

- No code other than the AWS SDK touches the sockets, or even knows about them.  All the HTTP work is done exclusively through AWS SDK.
- So, if something's closing them, it must be something in the AWS SDK.
- The code is running on an EC2 server; there's no reason to expect any type of network connectivity issues between EC2 and S3, and certainly no reason they should happen predictably (after an hour into the run) each time

Comment: Can you post some minimal code that reproduces the problem on a different data set? Can you also show your `netstat -tn` output when this occurs?

Comment: @b4hand - I will try to get all of this.  Since the problem only occurs after about 45 minutes, experimentation is slow.  It will take me a bit to do it, but I will try.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the answer, but http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html states that **"if you expect a rapid increase in the request rate for a bucket to more than 300 PUT/LIST/DELETE requests per second or more than 800 GET requests per second, we recommend that you open a support case to prepare for the workload and avoid any temporary limits on your request rate"**.  Perhaps since I exceeded the limit, AWS starts aborting connections; the SDK, detecting the IDLE sockets, closes them, and, voila!, we get exceptions.

**UPDATE:** Not sure if this is correct.  Amazon seems to state that, in this case, you'll get an explicit "Slow Down" error message, not an unexpected close.  So, the puzzle remains.

Comment: If I'm right, confirmation of this, and, more importantly, a solution - esp. one that works without needing a AWS Support Engineer - will still win the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

The Exception is SocketException caused by setSoTimeout() method in java.net.Socket.(See the stack trace). The method can be viewed here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/Socket.java#Socket.setSoTimeout%28int%29

Possible reason may be that the requests to S3  are still pending/incomplete resulting the thread to wait(). Once the wait time exceeds socket timeout , the socket is closed and exception is thrown.

Comment: Sandeep - Would that mean that simply raising the socket timeout should solve this problem?  I will try that.  Any guess as to why this happens only after about 40 minutes.

Comment: Looking at the code you posted, the exception is thrown when you try to set a timeout on a closed socket.  It is not thrown when a socket times out!

Comment: No. The method is *setting* the socket timeout, not *getting* one, and it is encountering a closed socket while it is doing so. If there was a read timeout there would be a `SocketTimeoutException`. This is completely back to front.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'd better try the `ClientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(int)`. If the socket is asynchronously closed, I think it's because of the timeout. According to the amazon document:

```
public void setSocketTimeout(int socketTimeout)

Sets the amount of time to wait (in milliseconds) for data to be transfered 
over an established, open connection before the connection times out and is closed. 
A value of 0 means infinity, and isn't recommended.
```

So, according to the document, if the connection times out, I think it is automatically closed.

link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setSocketTimeout(int)

Comment: A timeout expiry causes a SocketTimeoutException, not a closure.

Comment: @EJP, thanks for the comment. But according to the document, the connection can be asynchronously closed.

Comment: @EJP - Can you please elaborate on what's causing this to close, and, more importantly, what I do about it?

Comment: I think you'd better try to set explicit timeout to '0' or at least greater than two hours. For example, create `ClientConfiguration` object, call `setSocketTimeout(0)` to it, and pass it as an argument when you create an `AmazonHttpClient` object. Does it make sense?

Comment: @ByungjoonLee The word 'asynchronous' does not appear in the document you cited., and there is nothing there about throwing the OP's exception instead of a `SocketTimeoutException` either. And the OP's exception occurs *while setting the timeout*, which means it hasn't been set, which means it isn't *due* to the timeout expiring. You have this completely back to front.

Answer (score -3):

There is only one cause of this exception. You or your framework closed the socket and then continued to use it.

Comment: I'm not aware of JVMs arbitrarily closing sockets.  What causes the JVM to close it, and, more importantly, how do I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Please support your statement that the JVM is closing the socket.  I've never heard of this.

Comment: @SRobertJames I haven't said anything about JMVs 'arbitrarily' closing sockets. They don't. Your application does, or some buggy library. The assertion is supported by the Javadoc.

Comment: (Actually, the original answer did say "the JVM closed the socket" it.  After my comments, it was edited to "You closed the socket".)

Comment: @SRobertJames It didn't say 'arbitrarily'. That was your contribution.